# Need to evaluate the class of an element and loop through code while it's not true

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm having to automate a script that has a 'tear down' method to make sure the state of the page is where it was before we interacted with it. I am having issues figuring out exactly how to do this. My current idea is to perform a while loop when a certain element's state, via a class, does not exist or isn't visible in the DOM.

We have an 'undoAction' button that has its class updated to include 'undo-disabled' once there isn't anything to undo on the page, while leaving the original 'undoAction' class intact.

My problem is I can't find anything on the internet for a 'while not true' conditional.

Element when enabled:

```
<div class="undoAction  editor-topbar-item editor-topbar-icon-item"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></div>
```

Element when disabled:

```
<div class="undoAction undo-disabled editor-topbar-item editor-topbar-icon-item"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></div>
```

What I want to do is:

```
while(! .undo-disabled){
    .click(.undoAction)
}
```

I also tried to do this loop for when .undoAction is true, but the problem is they just add .undo-disabled to the list of classes for the element and don't remove the .undoAction class, so it goes into an infinite loop.

```
while(.undoAction){
    await t
        .click(.undoAction)

    if(.undo-disabled){
        break
    }
}
```

Without creating something to count the number of interactions I perform on the page and setting a for loop index to the number of interactions and decrement, is there any other way to handle this situation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to click an undo button repeatedly until it has the `undo-disabled` class added to it.

If that assumption is correct, one solution is to run a interval that runs every half second (or longer if needed) that will click the undo button. If it detects the `undo-disabled` class then it will clear the interval (stop it).

Note: There is probably a better way to do this behind the scenes without having to rely on the UI like this, but here is an example solution for what you have requested.

```js
let counter = 0; // just for this example and not needed.
const undoButton = document.querySelector(".undoAction");

// below event listener is just for this example and not needed
undoButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  ++counter;
  console.log(`undo click count: ${counter}`)
});


function startUndo() {
  const interval = setInterval(function() {
    const btn = document.querySelector(".undoAction")

    if (btn.classList.contains("undo-disabled")) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      return;
    }

    btn.click();

    // below "if" is just for this example and not needed
    if (counter === 4) {
      btn.classList.add("undo-disabled");
    }

  }, 500);
}


startUndo();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="undoAction editor-topbar-item editor-topbar-icon-item"><i class="fa fa-undo"></i></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to repeat clicking several times, reevaluate [DOM node state](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402670/reference/test-api/domnodestate) inside the loop. For example:

```
const button = Selector('.undoAction');
let disabled = await button.hasClass('undo-disabled');

while(!disabled) {
    await t.click(button);

    disabled = await button.hasClass('undo-disabled');
}
```

But, if you just want to wait until the class '.undo-disabled' will be added after one click, you can use an assertion like this:

```
await t.expect(button.hasClass('undo-disabled')).ok({ timeout: 30000 });
```